# CefSharp: Injecting custom CSS File using a custom scheme

Tags: winforms, cefsharp

I'm using CefSharp (47) to render a webpage from a host that I have no control over, and I want to make some additional CSS tweaks to those provided by the host.

Reading up on various topics across GitHub (https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/47/CefSharp.Example/CefSharpSchemeHandlerFactory.cs), and here ([CefSharp custom SchemeHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965912/cefsharp-custom-schemehandler)), I wrote a custom scheme handler accordingly:

```
public class CustomSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    public const string SchemeName = "custom";

    public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(request.Url);

        if (schemeName.ToLower() == SchemeName.ToLower())
        {
            // Do some stuff
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I attempt to bind it in my application in the following manner:

```
            CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
            settings.CachePath = browserCachePath;
            settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme()
            {
                SchemeName = CustomSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName,
                SchemeHandlerFactory = new CustomSchemeHandlerFactory()
            });
            Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

The application then browses to the appropriate website, and uses the 'LoadingStateChanged' event to then fire off some JavaScript to inject the CSS file I want to load:

```
        string linkText = "<link rel=\u0022stylesheet\u0022 type=\u0022text/css\u0022 href=\u0022custom://custom.css\u0022>";
        var jsFunctionText = string.Format("(function() {{ $('head').append('{0}'); return true;}}) ();", linkText);

        var injectionTask = await _myBrowser.GetMainFrame().EvaluateScriptAsync(jsFunctionText, null);
```

...which succeeds.

But my custom resource handler 'Create' event is never fired.

I can only presume that the handler isn't being registered properly, so I'd appreciate any advice/help in getting this working properly!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you checking `loadingStateChangedArgs.IsLoading == false` before calling your script? You can open `DevTools` and execute your script manually to make sure the syntax is correct, see that the `SchemeHandler` is called.

Comment: Yes, IsLoading is being checked before firing the script, (and success is always true).  I can't open the DevTools for an unknown reason (not looked into it) - but, it seems that after calling ShowDevTools() I get a Windows 8 notification saying that there's no application able to open the file type!

Comment: I have devtools_resources.pak in the executable directory (With a locales sub-folder).

Comment: ...and for a bit more info.  I added a periodical check through some more JS injection, to test all links in the DOM: var activeLinks = $('link');].  The custom scheme link is definitely there.

Comment: Debug.log has the reason why: [0405/130734:INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the stylesheet 'custom://custom.css/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'

Comment: Try adding a `host` portion to your `Url`. like `custom://local/custom.css`

Comment: Modifying the URL as suggested unfortunately has the same result.

Comment: What's the website your trying to add `css` to? `HTTP`? `HTTPS`? You can register your handler using one of those schemes and perform more precise url matching in the `ISchemeHandlerFactory`.

Comment: It's the Twitter TweetDeck site at https://tweetdeck.twitter.com.  So, are you thinking I should add a handler for http/https that returns null for requests that I want CEFSharp's default handler to deal with, but inject CSS using a custom URL, and handle that myself?

Comment: Something like that. `custom schemes` aren't registered as secure by default yet there's an open issue with the `CEF` project, see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1723/register-internal-schemes-as-secure-to

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/c3f33311482f33aafba7c7c2bbad678071e20732/CefSharp.Example/InMemorySchemeAndResourceHandlerFactory.cs for an example that demos the two options, `ISchemeHandlerFactory` or `IResourceHandlerFactory`, both are similar.