# WebAssembly(wasm) in CefSharp via custom scheme

Tags: c#, cefsharp, webassembly

Custom SchemeHandler incompatible with WASM?

I can't tell if my Scheme Handler can't handle WASM or WASM doesn't like my scheme handler.

I've essentially written a custom SchemeHandler along the lines of bartosz.baczek 's answer here: [CefSharp custom SchemeHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35965912/cefsharp-custom-schemehandler)

It works well for loading html, javascript, and CSS. It even successfully grants access to my camera.  It seems to be failing for WASM.

The web assembly works well hosted in IIS, but fails in the file loading for cefsharp. Consequently, a needed third party library can't be loaded.

Is this possible? We are trying to bypass deploying the library into a webserver. Custom Scheme Handler gets around problems using "file://" protocol and has other benefits.

Is it possible to get a wasm to understand a custom protocol without changing it's code? Perhaps a chromium flag?

Documentation has been ambiguous as to whether WASM is supported by CefSharp. Links point directly to Chromium.

Here's errors:

blob:customfileprotocol://c/098b5e97-58e4-44ee-b324-3e18fe5ac33f:1 **Fetch API cannot load customfileprotocol:**//blah/scandit-sdk/build/scandit-engine-sdk.wasm?v=4.3.0. URL scheme "customfileprotocol" is not supported.

blob:customfileprotocol://c/098b5e97-58e4-44ee-b324-3e18fe5ac33f:1 **TypeError: Failed to fetch**
    at blob:customfileprotocol://c/098b5e97-58e4-44ee-b324-3e18fe5ac33f:1
    at new Promise ()
    at blob:customfileprotocol://c/098b5e97-58e4-44ee-b324-3e18fe5ac33f:1
    at blob:customfileprotocol://c/098b5e97-58e4-44ee-b324-3e18fe5ac33f:1
    at new Promise ()
    at S (blob:customfileprotocol://c/098b5e97-58e4-44ee-b324-3e18fe5ac33f:1)
    at blob:customfileprotocol://c/098b5e97-58e4-44ee-b324-3e18fe5ac33f:1

**Couldn't retrieve/instantiate Scandit SDK Engine library at** : Blah

***CODE EXAMPE***

```
// SETTINGS AND REGISTRATION
 MySettings.JavascriptFlags = "--expose-wasm";


                MySettings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme {
                    SchemeName=CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory.SchemeName,
                    SchemeHandlerFactory=new CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory()


                });

// END SETTINGS

/// SCHEME HANDLER FACTORY

 public class CustomProtocolSchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
    {
        public const string SchemeName = "customFileProtocol";

        public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
        {
            return new CustomProtocolSchemeHandler();
        }
    }
//// END SCHEME HANDLER FACTORY


/// PROCESS REQUEST ASYNC

 public override bool ProcessRequestAsync(IRequest request, ICallback callback)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(request.Url);
            //var fileName = uri.AbsolutePath;
            string fileName = uri.LocalPath;


            var requestedFilePath = "C:/" + fileName;

            /*   var isAccesToFilePermitted = IsRequestedPathInsideFolder(
                   new DirectoryInfo(requestedFilePath),
                   new DirectoryInfo(frontendFolderPath));*/

            // if (isAccesToFilePermitted && File.Exists(requestedFilePath))
            string bFileName = "";

            bFileName = requestedFilePath;

            if (File.Exists(bFileName))
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(bFileName);
                Stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);


                var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(bFileName);
                MimeType = GetMimeType(fileExtension);

                callback.Continue();

                return true;
            }

            callback.Dispose();

            return false;
        }


/// END PROCESS REQUEST ASYNC
```

Comment: What version are you using?  How have you registered your scheme?  Provide a code example.

Comment: @amaitland . Done! Thanks for taking an interest.

Comment: @amaitland . Version 73.1.130.  x64 if that helps.

Comment: The error suggests it's trying to make a fetch request which support for was only added in version 75 which was released yesterday. Alternatively you can register your scheme handler for the built in https scheme that should have fetch already enabled,  I'd suggest you set the http://cefsharp.github.io/api/73.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefCustomScheme_DomainName.htm so you only get requests for a set domain.

Comment: If you choose to upgrade then enable fetch using http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/P_CefSharp_CefCustomScheme_IsFetchEnabled.htm

Comment: @amaitland. The upgrade made the wasm loading errors go away. Thanks! Attempts to put in a Domain name when registering a scheme opens up an html page with an empty <body> tag. I'm exploring this issue now.